# Dataset interpretation Continuous vs Categorical for House Prices

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm working with the UK house price dataset and was wanting to create a ML model to predict the price of a house based on the city (plus some other categories).

As a newb to all of this, I am stumped. I am fine creating models with continuous variables, or even carrying out one-hot encoding (dummy variables) for some of the other categories which have 4 different options (type of house for example).

However, when it comes to cities, there are about 1200 different cities in the data set and so I am not sure how to engineer the data to deal with this.

Would greatly appreciate anyone having any idea about this!

No matter how much I search, I can't find an answer to this, but this could perhaps be due to not knowing exactly what to search for.

Answer (score 0):

For me you need to have a city grade in every city and a price for a house.

For example:

```
Country     | City Grade 
------------+------------
Los Angeles |    1
New York    |    4

House       | Price
------------+------------
Option1     | $200,000
Option2     | $300,000
```

Then calculate the house price based on the city grade by multiplying house price * City Grade.

So it means the Option1 house in Los Angeles will still $200,000 but in New York would be $1,200,000.

You don't need to worry about the 1200 cities its easy to query in database.

Comment: Hey Kim, thanks for the post. Not sure if that helps me too much though. This would mean that I'd need to go through and grade each city before I could use it? The purpose here is to be able to put all this information into a model and then be able to use the model to predict the price of a single house.